“have a shot at” vs “have a bash at”
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'have a shot at' and 'have a bash (at)'? The definitions in the Collins dictionary are:

have a shot at : to attempt
have a bash (at) : to attempt; make an attempt


They mean the same, and are both equally informal.

Also have a go at, a stab at, a crack at, a bash at,...

Please edit to explain why you think there might be a difference.

I only want to be sure, because several times I have thought that two different words or idioms, etc. are exactly the same and then I'd find that there have been some differeces between them that often you can not find those differences in a dictionary. So I prefer whenever I doubt, I ask a question to be on the safe side!

No, there is no difference between the meanings here. They can be used interchangeably for "attempt", although "bash" is very British and would not be understood elsewhere.
"Have a shot at" has an additional meaning in US and Canadian English: "have a chance of succeeding".

If the Toronto Maple Leafs continue to improve they might have a shot at winning the Stanley Cup one day."

It doesn't mean "make an attempt" (they "attempt" this every year) but "have a chance of succeeding".
US and Canadians would generally say "take a shot at" when it means "attempt".

Pretty much the same for Brits.
